# VBA Get property

Tags: vba

I have a class module MyVBAclass which has a member of a custom COM class

```
Private mMyCOMclass As MyCOMclass
Public Property Get InnerClass() As MyCOMclass
    Set InnerClass = mMyCOMclass
End Property
Public Property Let InnerClass(value As MyCOMclass)
    Set mMyCOMclass = value
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mMyCOMclass = New MyCOMclass
End Sub
```

MyCOMclass has Clone() and CopyTo() methods implemented, Clone returns a new instance of MyCOMclass, and CopyTo just copies the properties to an already initialized object.
This is the problem that I have, and it would be great if someone could explain how can avoid it.

```
Dim MyVBAinstance As MyVBAclass
Set MyVBAinstance = New MyVBAclass

Dim COMinstance As MyCOMclass, copyOfCOM As MyCOMclass
Set COMinstance = New MyCOMclass
Set copyOfCOM = New MyCOMclass

' Do some stuff with COMinstance

Call COMinstance.CopyTo(copyOfCOM) ' Works fine
MyVBAinstance.InnerClass = COMinstance.Clone() ' Works fine even without Set

Call COMinstance.CopyTo(MyVBAinstance.InnerClass) ' DOESN'T WORK
```

Comment: What value does the Instancing property of MyVBAinstance class have? Have you tried to set it to '2 - public not creatable'?

Comment: I have expanded the question with Initialize if that's what you have asked. Also, this same code runs and all 3 ways of copying work fine with old version of the MyCOMclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of object orientation is that an object hides it's members from the outside world. The `GET` and `SET` properties act as a "gateway". This, no routine can simply override change the object underneath `MyVBAinstance.InnerClass`. What you need to do is:

```
Dim objTemp as As MyCOMclass
Set objTemp = New MyCOMclass 'this will reserve the memory and store the pointer in objTemp
Call COMinstance.CopyTo(objTemp) 'this will fill the allocated memory
Set MyVBAinstance.InnerClass = objTemp 'this will copy the pointer from objTemp to MyVBAinstance.InnerClass
```

<strike>If you want to expose some private members of your class, you need to provide the `PROPERTY GET` and `PROPERTY SET`/`PROPERTY LET` methods as you are doing. `GET` will be called every time you access the property - and `PROPERTY SET`/`PROPERTY LET` is called when you assign an object/value to the property.</strike>

If the property is an object, you need to use `PROPERTY SET` - if it is of a native type (Integer, String, etc.) you must use `PROPERTY LET`.

In the same way, you then need to assign objects to the property with `SET` (e.g. `Set MyVBAInstance.InnerClass = anotherObject`), but native types without `SET` (e.g. ' MyVBAInstance.Name = "Test"`)

Thus, in your code replace `LET` with `SET` here:

```
Public Property Set InnerClass(value As MyCOMclass)
    Set mMyCOMclass = value
End Property
```

and then also use the `SET` keyword in your code:

```
Set MyVBAinstance.InnerClass = COMinstance.Clone()
```

Comment: But this line with Clone() already works. Problem is with this last line.

Comment: are you sure, i.e. did you try something like `MyVBAinstance.InnerClass.MethodCall`?

Comment: If setting the class is not the issue, the problem is most likely in the `CopyTo` method...

Comment: I think so too, but why does it work when an object is passed to it directly (`Call COMinstance.CopyTo(copyOfCOM)`) and not when I go through Get, Let, Set ...

Comment: I really don't know, though I'm still wondering about the `LET`. Did you try it with `SET`?

Comment: Yes I did, but the thing is that in `Call COMinstance.CopyTo(MyVBAinstance.InnerClass)` it goes inside the `Get` of MyVBAclass, not `Set` or `Let`. So, it doesn't care if it is `Set` or `Let`. Can I somehow force it to use `Set`?

Comment: Check out the updated answer - I first added some information why you should use `SET` - but then realised it's a different issue, so I changed it (but left the explanation for your info, as I still believe its valid in your case)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanation. I have to ask the developers of the MyCOMclass, to see what have they changed inside it, because this code worked with the previous version, and the code only had Get property. Thank you very much.

Comment: you're welcome! don't forget to upvote/accept as an answer if it solved you problem!